# MATLAB data tips - better accuracy

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

G'day,

Have been provided a p-code MATLAB program to find data tips from a graph. [Attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3MMQj.jpg) is an image of a step response of unknown magnitude of a water tank system.

For better accuracy, I would like to extract data at discrete intervals instead of zooming in and attempting to click on a whole number. Is there a way of doing this through the graph/data tips, without writing code.

Is this even possible with a graph received from a P-code? or will I have to just average out multiple attempts.

Cheers

Comment: Is the output of your code an image, or a MATLAB figure?

Comment: Do you have your data cursor set to "mouse position" or "nearest point"? The latter would at least snap to the actual data points, which are presumably sensibly spaced

Comment: The output of the P-code is a MATLAB figure, where I can place data tips on it.